# Using HTML Canvas to make a Choropleth Map

Tags: html5-canvas, choropleth

I attempting to make a Choropleth Map using HTML Canvas.  If you are unfamiliar with Choropleth Maps they are basically a map that has different regions shaded with different colors.  What I am trying to do is use the canvas fill() method to color different states on the US map.  However, fill seems to only work if I have drawn an outline on my canvas.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
```

Here I want to put something like `var c =ctx.fillMap();` however this won't work as Map is the entire US map and I just want to fill in a single state.

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with hot areas in HTML. You may read about it here: [MDN area)(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) and [MDN map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map). By the other hand this is a pen that lets you to [Create a Hot Area with map](https://codepen.io/giaco/pen/mGPdgb) You can drag and drop an image from your computer and then you can click the image to create a polygonal shape over the image. (the hot area).

Comment: Although this is a [link to the Spanish Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205747/delimitar-%C3%A1reas-especificas-de-una-imagen-y-asociarla-a-un-evento-click/205781#205781) here you can see a demo where I draw a pink clickable area over a building. I'm doing it with `<map>` (the first demo) and with SVG (the second demo). I don't think you need Spanish to understand it. Please take a look at the code and if this is what you need come back and ask a better question